# Split input name attribute in nested rails form with javascript

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, forms, nested

First off, I am having trouble describing my issue. I apologize in advanced if I am not seeing an existing answer online. How can I split this string into an array where each entry is the text within each set of square brackets. Here is the string:

```
plan_year[benefit_groups_attributes][0][relationship_benefits_attributes][1][premium_pct]
```

What I need to do is store the value in second set of square brackets. In this example it is [0]. .split hasn't given me the result I wanted, and I think it is because I am doing

```
.split(/[[]]/);
```

Should I expect something like this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var s = 'plan_year[benefit_groups_attributes][0][relationship_benefits_attributes][1][premium_pct]';
s.match(/\[.*?\]/g)[1]; # "[0]"
```